Which API calls are used by Databricks Auto Loader in s3?
hey guys im using autoloader in databricks with an s3 bucket for json files.
I am wondering what the pricing will be since I found an article that describes the cost per api call.
Talking to chat it told me that autoloader will perform a list call and then x number of get calls where x is the number of files per ingestion.
In order to estimate the yearly cost I need to understand what requests is autoloader sending

Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?

Hi @DarkBee i am not asking for you guys to calculate the cost, i am asking the calls it will make, maybe i gave too much context, but my goal is not for you guys to answer that. I'll edit the question so that it is more clear

To know for sure, you'll probably need to Log requests with server access logging - Amazon Simple Storage Service. Each ListBucket call only returns 1000 objects, so the number of calls would also depend on how many objects are currently in the bucket.

thx @JohnRotenstein will try this out
